# OpenGL shader - overlaping multiple textures

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, multitexturing

I am not able to find a pattern to draw textures one over other.
I need to make result fragment color like:

tex1 + (1-tex1alpha)*tex2 + (1-tex1alpha-tex2alpha)*tex3

Not to mix textures , but to place one over other like layers in image editor.

Comment: Does your scenario allow drawing the geometry several times with different textures?

Comment: What happens if you write that into your vertex shader?

Comment: I need to calculate fragment color in shader. My top texture has only black color and transparency, so when i use color1 + color2, black color will not apear.

Comment: So you need the color of the topmost texture where alpha==1. Determining that should be no problem (e.g. with a for loop).

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Maybe you need to review [compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) operations. Unless you're also scaling `tex1` by some alpha value, the RGB values probably aren't being weighted properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use OpenGL, so the GLSL code might not be completely valid. But the shader you are looking for should look something like this. Feel free to correct any mistakes.

```
vec4 col;
col = texture2D(tex3, uv)
if(col.a == 1) { gl_FragColor = col; return; }
col = texture2D(tex2, uv)
if(col.a == 1) { gl_FragColor = col; return; }
col = texture2D(tex1, uv)
if(col.a == 1) { gl_FragColor = col; return; }
```

That is if the number of textures is fixed. If you have a variable number of textures, you could put them into a texture array and do something like:

```
vec4 col;
for(int i = nTextures - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    col = texture2DArray(textures, vec3(uv, i));
    if(col.a == 1)
    {
        gl_FragColor = col;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the formula you posted directly in to the shader. The following will work:

```
uniform sampler2D sampler1;
uniform sampler2D sampler2;
uniform sampler2D sampler3;

varying vec2 texCoords;

void main()
{
    vec4 tex1 = texture(sampler1, texCoords);
    vec4 tex2 = texture(sampler2, texCoords);
    vec4 tex3 = texture(sampler3, texCoords);
    gl_FragColor = tex1 + (1 - tex1.a) * tex2 + (1 - tex1.a - tex2.a) * tex3;
};
```

However the 3rd argument could turn negative, which would have undesired results. Better would be:

```
gl_FragColor = tex1 + (1 - tex1.a) * tex2 + max(1 - tex1.a - tex2.a, 0) * tex3;
```